# Java Generic Response Issue in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a problem about making a jeneric response for this method in my Spring Boot example.
In signup, there are two response type (Generic message and UserDto). That's why I want to use jeneric response but I couldn't do that.

How can I do that?

Here is the method shown below.

```
public (Generic Resposne) signup(SignUpRequest signUpRequest){
    ....
    return MessageResponse.builder()
                    .message("Error: Username is already taken!")
                    .build();
    ....
    return UserDto.builder()
                .id(user.getId())
                .username(user.getUsername())
                .build();
}
```

Comment: Wrap the response in a `ResponseEntity`. Also, what version of Java are you using? because you cannot return different types from a single function up Java 8 (Don't know if this is permitted in newer versions). You'd need to generalize UserDto and MessageResponse so that they are the same (sub)type or use a much more generic type, like `org.json.JSON`. Check this tutorial for a [good introduction](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity) to `ResponseEntity`

Comment: @JettoMartínez I use java 11 version.

Comment: @JettoMartínez I tried `ResponseEntity<?>` but it didn't help me fix my issue.

Comment: I'd recommend against wildcards `?` in this scenario since the content of the wrapper is the important part. If the content were irrelevant, wildcards are handy. I suggest you use a different object, like raw `JSON`. The way you are trying to handle things seems like a bad API design IMO. You really want to properly generalize your endpoints. Another option is, using `ResponseEntity<UserDto>`, to return a `NULL` `UserDto` with an appropriate http status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface and implement both other types with it.

```java
public interface Response
```

```java
public class UserDto implements Response
```

```java
public class MessageResponse implements Response
```

```java
public Response signup(SignUpRequest signUpRequest){
    ....
    return MessageResponse.builder()
                    .message("Error: Username is already taken!")
                    .build();
    ....
    return UserDto.builder()
                .id(user.getId())
                .username(user.getUsername())
                .build();
}
```